# SQL query to combine two rows into one as result

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have one requirement to write an SQL Server query to read from one table, let's assume the table is called Table1, the structure and rows look like this:

[image]

The key is if the column RefID has value, for example, row 2 has RefID value 3, it refers to another row's ID (row 3), and row 3 must also have a not-null RefID and the value must be the ID of the first one. The idea is these two belong to the same object so I would like to get them as one result row.

I know I can do inner join on the same table like this:

```
select T1.*, T2.* from Table1 T1 inner join Table1 T2 on T1.RefID = T2.ID
where T1.ID is not null
```

But the thing is the result has redundancy: the result would have 4 rows and as I mentioned, since row 2 and row 3 together represent one object, I would like to only get 2 rows: one for row 2 row 3, and the other for row 4 row 5. How can I do that?

Comment: How do you want to select the two rows 2 and 3 in one row? what aggregate functions you want to use? Please paste the desired data for the two rows of the sample data you posted, this will explain what do you want to get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make sure that their IDs are ordered in a row:

```
select T1.*, T2.* from Table1 T1 inner join Table1 T2 on T1.RefID = T2.ID AND T1.ID < T2.ID
where T1.ID is not null
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That works on my SQL Server test. But I failed to mention that this is a Access DB and apparently the syntax is a bit different. The same query doesn't work and it just pops up a window asking me to input Parameter T1 (some link say Access doesn't allow alias for column but I am using alias, and I must since I am joining the same table, in tables). Do you happen to know the correct query on Access?

Answer (score 1):

if the records are redundant and ID column is unique i am totaly aggree with @bulat you dont need to where clause they are already eliminated. i thing this query will works for you.

```
select * from Table1 a inner join Table1 b ON a.ID=b.RefID and a.ID>b.ID
```